# Mockup конструкторы

Tags: html, css, mockup

Подскажите хороший конструктор шаблонов и заодно дизайна, где можно выгружать это все в html разметку и желательно, что бы был онлайн.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отличный вариант - [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/). Но в исходном виде не совсем удовлетворяет Вашим требованиям - не онлайн, и не выгружает в html. Но тут есть парочка но:

- могут [интергироваться](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/gdrive) с Google Drive
- есть [конвертер](http://development.nedeco.de/blog/2011/11/03/balsamiq-mockups-to-htmlcss-converter/) в HTML

Но он платный.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле их ой как много:

- [UXPin](https://www.uxpin.com/)
- [MockFlow](http://mockflow.com)
- [HotGloo](http://hotgloo.com)
- [Moqups](http://moqups.com)
- [Lumzy](http://lumzy.com)
- [Pidoco](http://pidoco.com)
- [Frame Box](http://framebox.org)
- [Mockup Builder](http://mockupbuilder.com)
- [InVision](http://invisionapp.com)